# Quick sort implementation

Tags: c, quick-sort

> Please look the code below

```
#include<stdio.h>
void quicksort(int *,int ,int);
int partition1(int *,int ,int);
void swap1(int *,int *);

int main()
{

int low = 0;
int length;
int i;
int a[100];
int high;

printf("Enter  the length of array\n");
scanf("%d",&length);

high=length-1;

printf("Enter the array elememts\n");

for(i=0;i<=high;i++)
{
 scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}

quicksort(a,low,high);

printf("The sorted array\n");

for(i=low;i<=high;i++)
{
  printf("%d--",a[i]);
}

 printf("\n");
 return 0;
}

void quicksort(int a[],int low,int high)
{
   int p;

  if(low<high)
  {
     p=partition1(a,low,high);
     quicksort(a,low,p-1);
     quicksort(a,p+1,high);
  }
}


 int partition1(int a[],int low,int high)
{
   int pivot=a[high];
   int i=low-1;
   int j=low;

   for(j=low;j<high;j++)
  {
      if(a[j]<a[high])
      {
         i++;
         swap1(&a[i],&a[j]);
      }
  }
        swap1(&a[i+1],&a[high]);
        return i+1;
}

  void swap1(int* a,int* b)
 {
   int  temp;
   temp=*a;
   *a=*b;
   *b=temp;
 }
```

This is the working program of quick sort.Can anyone tell me the way to make this program much better?

> please do the necessary changes  required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Coding conventions**

1. Have at least one empty line after all `#include`s.
2. Have one space character before and after every binary operator. For example, **`a + 1`** instead of **`a+1`**. That makes your code easier to read.
3. Have one space after each **`for`** keyword: not **`for(i=1;i<10;i++)`**, but rather 
    **`for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)`**. (Same applies to **`if`**.)
4. Fix your indentation:

```
for(j=low;j<high;j++)
  {
      if(a[j]<a[high])
      {
         i++;
         swap1(&a[i],&a[j]);
      }
  }
```

to

```
for(j=low;j<high;j++)
{
    if(a[j]<a[high])
    {
        i++;
        swap1(&a[i], &a[j]);
    }
}
```

5. Instead of writing **`&a[index]`** you can write simply **`a + index`**.
6. Whenever printing a simple (non-formated) standard output, use **`puts`** instead of **`printf`**. (Also, note that **`puts`** automatically adds the new line character after the argument string.)

All the above points are relevant to readability of your source code.

**Summa summarum**

All in all, I had this in mind:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void quicksort(int*, int, int);
int partition(int*, int, int);
void swap(int*, int*);

int main()
{
    int low = 0;
    int length;
    int i;
    int a[100];
    int high;

    puts("Enter the length of array:");
    scanf("%d", &length);

    high = length - 1;

    puts("Enter the array elements:");

    for (i = 0; i <= high; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    quicksort(a, low, high);

    puts("The sorted array:");

    for (i = low; i <= high; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }

    puts("");
    return 0;
}

void quicksort(int a[],int low,int high)
{
    int p;

    if (low < high)
    {
        p = partition(a, low, high);
        quicksort(a, low, p - 1);
        quicksort(a, p + 1, high);
    }
}


int partition(int* a, int low, int high)
{
    int pivot = a[high];
    int i = low;
    int j;

    for (j = low; j < high; ++j)
    {
        if (a[j] <= pivot)
        {
            swap(a + i++, a + j);
        }
    }

    swap(a + i, a + high);
    return i;
}

void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

Hope that helps.